# Is there a way to roll-back the Android Plug-in on Netbeans?

Tags: android, plugins, netbeans, rollback

I went ahead and installed the latest Android Plug-in for Netbeans not realizing that it required the new Sdk. I am unable to get the newest SDK and now my project won't compile.

So I'm wondering, is there a way to roll-back the plug-in so that I can compile my project again.

If it matters, I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1 and the last update for the plug-in was Oct. 28th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you [uninstall plugin](http://wiki.netbeans.org/PluginUninstallation) and install your previous version?

Comment: I had uninstalled it initially, but I couldn't find the previous version at the developers site: http://www.nbandroid.org/ Upon adding the plugin into Netbeans it wants me to install the newest plugin

Comment: you can goto : http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/downloads/  and manually download the desired version.

Comment: When attempting to install the plugin from file, I'm unsure of which .nbm to choose from? Do I go back and select all of them? Meaning I would have to add about 13 plugins?  (It looks like there is one for logcat, testrunning, sdklib, etc)

Comment: While I was able to install the plug-ins, I was unable to successfully run my app. I believe this is due to some of the changes the latest plugin made when it was installed.